# ping returns Name or service not know from container. DNS request are forwarded to the host and I can reach URL from host

Tags: docker, url, dns, containers, host

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.4
```

I build and deploy container locally on my windows 10. On my host machine I can connect to
`https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-03-30/src/contrib/PACKAGES` without any problem

From container when I try (after installing ping utility)

```
ping https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-03-30/src/contrib/PACKAGES
```

I get back:

```
Name or service not known
```

Reading about DNS led to me check `etc/resolv.conf`. In this file I found:

```
# DNS requests are forwarded to the host. DHCP DNS options are ignored.
nameserver 192.168.65.5
```

What is wrong why I cannot reach url from container?

Comment: TRy running your container in the `host` network....something like `docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`...add the `--network host` to you `run` command 

Comment: @Hackerman, thank you.  I ran: `docker run --network host -it myfolder/myimage bin/bash`, but it did not help. `-it bin/bash` is in order to run it interactively. I am also thinking `ping` is not right command to check `https` connection. I do not know what would be better command to check connection to my https.

Comment: `ping` works with hostname (or IP addresses) and not URL. So `ping https://....` will never work. And anyway `ping` is almost always the wrong troubleshooting tool. If you want to troubleshoot DNS issues, use a DNS client, like `dig`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thank you! Could you recommend something to check connection to my url in the post?

Comment: If you want to test HTTP/HTTPS use an HTTP(s) client such as `curl`,`wget`, etc. It will give you details about HTTP problems. If you need to debug DNS issues, use `dig`.